# Do any whole number solutions exist for $a^2 + b^3 = 2^{2023}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

Do any whole number solutions exist for $a^2 + b^3 = 2^{2023}$?

And if so, would it be possible to give an example of one?

This problem is meant to be solved with modular-arithmetic and I could not even get started.
Guessing that you must find the right modulus such that no squares or cubes can be added to reach the mod of $2^{2023}$.

For example all squares in mod $8$ are $0$, $1$ or $4$. And all cubes have in mod $13$ class $0$, $\pm1$, $\pm 5$.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is

> Do any whole number solutions exist for $a^2 + b^3 = 2^{2023}$

One potential solution would be if $a^2 = b^3 = 2^{2022}$.
Note that this has obvious solutions $a = 2^{2022/2} = 2^{1011}$ and
$b = 2^{2022/3} = 2^{674}.$ There may be other non-obvious solutions.

---

This is an example of an elliptic curve. The base case in standard
Weierstrass form is

$$ y^2 = x^3 + 2 \tag1 $$

which is the [curve with Cremona label 1728a1](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/1728a1). This curve has the
obvious points $(x,y) = (-1,\pm 1).$ Each is a generator for the group
of *rational* points. All other rational points are not integral.

In your case, you want something like

$$ y^2 = x^3 + 2^{1+6k} \tag2 $$

or equivalently,

$$ (y/8^k)^2 = (x/4^k)^3 + 2. \tag3 $$

The problem now becomes to find a solution $(x,y)$ of equation $(1)$
where the denominator of $x$ is $4^k$ which seems to be impossible if
$k>0$.

Comment: The obvious solution was the one my teacher expected. Thanks for helping