# Elliptic divisibility sequence $a_n$ for $y^2 = x^3 + 2$ and point $(-1,1)$ divisibility conjecture

Tags: recurrence-relations, divisibility, elliptic-curves

In my answer to a recent
[MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4875434/)
I mention the elliptic curve
[LMFDB 1728.n4](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/1728a1)
with an infinite order generator and integer points $(-1,\pm1)$. The
[elliptic divisibility sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_divisibility_sequence)
associated with the generator is defined by initial values
and recursions

$$ a_0 = 0,\; a_1 = 1,\; a_2 = 2,\; a_3 = -21,\; a_4 = -284, \\
a_{-n} = -a_n,\;\;\; a_n = (4a_{n-1}a_{n-3} + 21a_{n-2}^2)/a_{n-4}, \\
a_{2n+1} = a_{n+2}a_n^3 - a_{n+1}^3a_{n-1},\\
a_{2n} = a_n(a_{n+2}a_{n-1}^2 - a_{n-2}a_{n+1}^2)/2. $$

The sequence $a_n$ can be computed with the PARI/GP code

```
a(n) = subst(elldivpol(ellinit([0, 2]), n), 'x, -1)/(2 - n%2);
print(vector(9, n, a(n)))
/* [1, 2, -21, -284, 6989, 553350, -18912521, -20779585336, 5506106985351] */
```

I conjecture that $2^k|a_n$ if and only if $2^k|n$ for all integers
$n>0, k\ge 0.$ In other words, $\nu_2(n) = \nu_2(a_n)$ for the $2$-adic
valuation.  I tested the conjecture up to $n=999.$
I can prove this is true for all $n$ odd. Perhaps this can be extended
to a proof by induction on the $2$-adic valuation.
Can anyone supply either a complete proof or else a counterexample?

Comment: Any elliptic curve has an infinity of integer points. Maybe i have misunderstood your post.

Comment: @Piquito A rank 0 elliptic curve has only finitely many rational points ($\leq 16$, in fact), hence finitely many integral points.

Comment: @ViktorVaughn: There are not elliptic curves having an infinity of integer points. This is what I wanted to say in my comment with my deficient English. (your  $\le16$ is a fundamental result of Mazur; I know well what you want to teach me because my doctoral tesis in France was on elliptic curves precisely)

Comment: May be @Piquito wanted to say that *No elliptic curve has infinitely many integer points*, but the choice of English phrase turned the meaning upside down?

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: My main problem is the difficulty of writting because my English is quite elementary (many times I am misunderstood because of this deficiency) Thanks you very much for your comment.